# replace typescript class on node module on ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules, ag-grid

I encountered the following problem. I have ag-grid library on my project.But this library does not consist from certain functionality.

I downloaded the source ag-grid.And did necessary changes(I changed some class and scss files).
for example i replaced following class:

```
export class Component extends BeanStub implements IComponent<any> {
```

Can i replace this files on my common project if i will import their on my project? Or if ask another.Can i replace files of node modules on my project?

Comment: You can create your own classes in your project by extending the ones in the library.

Comment: you could create own fork of this library and use that but then you would have to maintain it and update with any changes from main repo. That can be easier than in some cases creating extension to library components that dont support plugin approach for extending their functionalities. I am not sure what is ag-grid philosophy of extending functionalities. But you can research if there is alternative way of extending thing with use of dependency injection.